# PHP cannot redeclare a variable

Tags: php

```
class Content extends CodonModule     {

    public $title = 'Operations';
    public function operations()     {

        $this->show('operations');

    }

    public $title = 'Staff';
    public function staff()     {

        $this->show('staff');

    }

}
```

I'm trying to give every template a title, but it can't redeclare a class, how can I bypass this? I tried putting public $title inside the function, but that doesn't follow the documentation, and doesn't work, it just throws an undefined T_PUBLIC error.

Comment: You have two lines that declare the variable $title... your second line should only say $title = 'Staff';

Comment: I'm trying to give every public function a name. Essentially, the public function shows a template with HTML code on it. public $title should set the HTML title of each template/page.

Comment: Declare `public $title` once, and set its value in the methods.  Inside `operations()`, do `$this->title = 'operations'`.  Likewise in `staff()`

Comment: @AMayer: Have you tried that?

Comment: @Glavić I have... Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE, expecting T_FUNCTION

Comment: @AMayer: ;-) @zzwyb89: I don't get this question, title is 'cannot redeclare a class', but your are talking about variables within class. Which is it now? Your example should return `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Content::$title in XXX.php on line 999`

Comment: It is `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare Content::$title`. I've sorted out the title, apologies.

Comment: the title and content of the question dont match. in the content of the question they say they get a T_Public error. its because they declared the variable twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in a comment by Michael Berkowski, set the title inside the functions. This will cause the title to be set as the function is called.

```
class Content extends CodonModule     {

    public $title;

    public function operations()     {
        $this->title = 'Operations';
        $this->show('operations');

    }

    public function staff()     {
        $this->title = 'Staff';
        $this->show('staff');

    }

}
```

Comment: I was confused by his explanation, your example made it more clear to a PHP newbie like me, thank you. What I didn't understand or initially misread, was the `public $title`, I thought it needs the define to be able to work. Thanks to Michael Berkowski too.

Answer (score 3):

This file is included/required several times in a row. You can have only 1 class defined with this name, but you can have several objects as instances of this class.

Comment: Yes, so my class is content. Essentially, it should display pages like /content/operations and /content/staff with individual public $title from the PHP above. For instance, public $title = 'Operations' for the first example should return <title>Operations</title> on the site and so on. I'm just wondering how to bypass the class redeclare issue.

Comment: make instances of classes dont include it again. $title = new Content(); $body = new Content(); $footer = new Content(); is this what you are looking for?